# How can I improve the performance of this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

In this query I make a "left join" with a table (ASPECT_CONTACT_EVENTS) that have many registers (In this period, 250.000).

The table Promessas have a 200 registes in this period.

```html
SET @inicio = '2015-02-24 00:00:00';

SET @fim = '2015-02-24 23:59:00';

SELECT Promessas.Data_acordo, if(Ativos.account_number IS NULL,
IF(Promessas.tipo_acordo='A VISTA',"11-QTDE DE PROMESSAS A VISTA (RECEPTIVO)","12-QTDE DE PROMESSAS PARCELADO (RECEPTIVO)"),
IF(Promessas.tipo_acordo='A VISTA',"05-QTDE DE PROMESSAS A VISTA (ATIVO)","06-QTDE DE PROMESSAS PARCELADO (ATIVO)"))  AS TIPO,

COUNT(DISTINCT Promessas.id_contr), Promessas.cluster FROM DWH_RBZ.tb_itau_banco_promessa_dia as Promessas
left join DWH_RBZ.ASPECT_CONTACT_EVENTS AS Ativos on ((Ativos.account_number = Promessas.id_contr) and (time_of_contact between (@inicio) and (@fim)) )
Where Promessas.data_acordo between (@inicio) and (@fim)
Group By tipo, Promessas.cluster;
```

How can I improve this performance?

Comment: How long does the query take now?  How long do you want it to take?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimizer does not do well with @variables.  Please put the values directly into the query and see if that speeds up the query.

Otherwise, `Promessas` needs an index starting with `data_acordo` in hopes that the WHERE clause can use the index.  The second table, `Ativos` needs a compound `INDEX(account_number, time_of_contact)`, assuming that times_of_contact is in that table.  Please use aliases on all fields!